# Effects of the discrete quotient of chiral symmetry group

Tags: symmetry, group-theory, quantum-chromodynamics, quarks, chirality

For a theory of $N_f$ massless Dirac fermions coupled to a Yang-Mills field, the usual story is that we have a $U_L(N_f)\times U_R(N_f)$ symmetry, which is then expressed as
$SU_L(N_f)\times SU_R(N_f) \times U_V(1) \times U_A(1)$.

However, since $U(n)\cong \left(SU(n)\times U(1)\right)/ \mathbb{Z}_n $, shouldn't the above include the quotient by the centers of $U_L(N_f)$, $U_R(N_f)$?

What are the possible physical effects of this?

Answer (score 1):

Keeping track of discrete chiral symmetries is important for discrete anomaly matching, see [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.07666). In QCD discrete anomaly matching can be used to exclude the option that spontaneous chiral symmetry does not lead to a chiral condensate $\langle\bar{q}q\rangle$, but is signaled by the vev of a higher dimension operator, such as $\langle(\bar{q}q)^2\rangle$.

Comment: Great, and thanks for the reference!